# click outside query dialog and interact with other elements on my page

Tags: jquery, events, dialog, click

i wanna click outside my jquery dialog after open it and for example select a link or interact with other elements like text, or div or something else, how could I manage with it ?

code that open dialog:

```
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 200,
        dialogClass: "noOverlayDialog",
        title: "WEB TV",
        open: function(ev, ui) {
            jQuery('#myIframe').attr('src', 'www.www.www');
            $('.noOverlayDialog').next('div').css({'opacity':0.0, 'z-index':-1});
        }
    });

    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

if i click on a link for example to change page the link is not working, i wanna be able to change page when my dialog is still open

Comment: could you provide us a simple example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You'll probably have to remove something, but I'm not sure what. Can you provide your relevant code and markup?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-_allowInteraction